# JavaScript Refresh page and set image width and height of Source(blob)

Tags: javascript, blob, height, width

I would like to know please

1. How to Refresh var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
2. and set the width and height of blob

It's from a App that sends a Base64String Image(WebCam)

I would like to Refresh portion of the page to get the new Image.
It works manually ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id="photo" width="400" height="400"/>

<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", "http://192.168.1.186:8080/dwkpic.html", true );
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function( e ) {
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    var img = document.querySelector( "#photo" );
    img.src = imageUrl;
};
xhr.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried  setTimeout()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id="photo" width="400" height="400"/>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", "http://192.168.1.186:8080/dwkpic.html", true );
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function( e ) {
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    var img = document.querySelector( "#photo" );
    img.src = imageUrl;
img.width="400";
img.height="400";
};
xhr.send();
}, 10);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what your trigger is for refresh? Is it event based or time based? If you just want to run the same code one more time, you can use setInterval. So code runs every whatever interval you choose. and when you are done you can clear interval so it stops

Comment: I wish to run the code every 100ns, so it can get a image from a server

Comment: JS cant do in ns, JS can do for milliseconds. So you may have to use some streaming API to achieve it. It seems you are trying to display video by fetching frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to run the function periodically, you just have to use setInterval instead of timeout.

```
setInterval(function(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", "http://192.168.1.186:8080/dwkpic.html", true );
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function( e ) {
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    var img = document.querySelector( "#photo" );
    img.src = imageUrl;
img.width="400";
img.height="400";
};
xhr.send();
}, 10);
```

but keep in mind, this approach will make 100 requests per second which is a lot of requests. So it is possible that browser might get overloaded.

I think what you want to do is actually streaming data, so you can maybe look at at how to stream data to browser.I don't know if you control the backend but if you do, you can also pipe the data.